# Besides Roman numeral analysis and chord analysis what other analyses are there?

Tags: theory

Besides Roman numeral analysis and chord analysis, what other analyses are there? What are those called?
Roman numeral analysis does, for example, say very little about the melody or non-chord tones.

Answer (score 1):

There are many...

- Cadence identification is very important for analyzing form. This is *not* the same as harmonic analysis `V I` isn't a cadence... unless you analyze it as such, symbols like: PAC, HC, DC are used for perfect authentic cadence, half cadence, deceptive cadence, etc.
- Non-chord tones, as you mention, can be analyzed: sus, app, pt, etc. for suspension, appoggiatura, passing tone, etc.
- Melody can be analyzed with scale degree symbols like `^1, ^2, ^3` which mean tonic, supertonic, mediant of the scale, these are similar to solfege syllabals like `DO, RE, MI` which can be used for analysis too.
- Fugue has its own terminology: subject, answer, counter-subject, stretto, exposition, episode, etc. used to analyze the design of fugues.
- Motivic development is another place for analysis combining some melodic aspects like sequence, inversion, interval transformation with rhythmic aspects like repetition, augmentation, diminution, etc.

Comment: It may be useful to Anglicise those cadence terms. A lot of us on the right hand side of the pond haven't much idea of what those terms represent!

Answer (score 1):

One can also use a figured bass treatment (preferably along with Roman Numeral analysis). This gives one an idea of the harmonic skeleton (or foundation) being used. For stuff (not that there's much) that I analyze for myself, I use Roman Numerals with figured bass figures and note various cadence points or other interesting happenings. (When playing I call V7/V a II7 but when analyzing,it's a V7/V or even V65/V7 then when playing I think II65. I suppose one could be consistent.)

I do try to mark secondary dominants, Neapolitans, Augmented Sixths, even when secondary during analysis. I tend to incorporated "resolved" ninth chords into the harmony and everything else gets shoved into the melody.

If the music consists of mostly independent lines (like Renaissance Counterpoint), one probably needs to write out the melodies separately.